# Converting Coldfusion - What does a posted WDDX request look like?

Tags: coldfusion, wddx

I'm in the process of trying to convert an old CF script.  The only problem is I am using CommandBox and I can't seem to get Fiddler to show me what this request looks like when it's actually posted.  Does anyone know what the Post request this sends out would look like?

I've tried a variety of options so far and nothing has worked.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<!--- 
    Cold Fusion 4.0.1
--->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">


<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<cfif isdefined("Form.thisid")>
    <!--- Input Form Parameters --->
    <cfset InputPbn = Form.thisid>
    <cfoutput>
    <h1>Raw XML data for #thisid#</h1>
    </cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <h1>A valid thisid was not provided</h1>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>


<!--- Assemble the user's input into structure --->

<CFSCRIPT>
    // New request structure to pass 
    Request = StructNew();
    
    Request.thisid = "#Inputthisid#";
    host_url = "http://myurl/get_info_wddx.cfm"; 

    Request["LINK_KEY"] = "1234";
    
</CFSCRIPT>

<!--- Convert the structure to WDDX Packet --->  

<CFWDDX 
    INPUT="#Request#"
    OUTPUT="RequestAsWDDX"
    ACTION="CFML2WDDX"
>

<cfoutput>RequestAsWDDX #HTMLEditFormat(RequestAsWDDX)#<br/></cfoutput>
<!--- Post the WDDX Packet to the host page as a form field --->

<CFTRY>
    <CFHTTP URL="#host_url#" METHOD="POST">
        <CFHTTPPARAM 
          NAME="WDDXContent" 
          VALUE="#RequestAsWDDX#" 
          TYPE="FORMFIELD"
        >
    </CFHTTP>
    <CFCATCH TYPE="Any">
        WDDX - HTTP Error<BR>
        <CFOUTPUT>#HTMLEditFormat(CFHTTP.FileContent)#</CFOUTPUT><BR>
        <CFABORT>
    </CFCATCH>
</CFTRY>
 
<!--- Extract recordset from WDDX Packet in host's response --->
<cfif FindNoCase("<META",CFHTTP.FileContent) >
    <cfset pos = FindNoCase(">",CFHTTP.FileContent)>
    <cfset wddx_strg = Right(CFHTTP.FileContent,(Len(CFHTTP.FileContent)-pos-1))>
<cfelse>
    <cfset wddx_strg = CFHTTP.FileContent>
</cfif>


...


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't the `<cfoutput>` tag show you what `RequestAsWDDX` looks like?

Comment: I don't know much of anything about CF. If that is the format of the WDDX. how is it sent to the requested url?  Sorry I'm really out of my element here.

Is it not possible to do something like "http://myurl/get_info_wddx.cfm?inputpbn=thisid" to get a WDDX formatted page returned to me?

Answer (score 0):

I was severely overcomplicating this ha, just had to use "WDDXContent" as the Key and the WDDXContent value as the value.

Edit: I have no code for this at this point, just was able to get fiddler to reproduce it by adding a header key "WDDXContent" and value

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><struct><var name='link_key'><string>1234</string></var><var name='id'><string>[id here]</string></var></struct></data></wddxPacket>
```

Comment: You should show what your code change is so that the next person can understand.